# I'm attempting to calculate the average and standard deviation of the (max,min,mean) temperatures for every day over the entire year in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Requirements: I consider the year to be made of 365-days, even if it's actually a leap year, plotting the ensuing curve and along with the standard deviation curves as error bars, and use the function errorbar for my standard deviation.  When I run the code, it generates the plot in a weird way that prevents me from fully seeing the issue:
[image].  Could some one help me resolve/fix the issue.

This is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import datetime

def ReadData(fname,Tmax,Tmin,Tave,dates, filterYear):    
    '''    
Read the temperature variation data and append four lists containing the maximum
temperatures as floats, the minimum temperatures as floats, the average
temperatures as floats, and the dates as string YYYYMMDD format.
    '''
    fileObj = open(fname,'r') # associate the fileObj variable with filename
    lineList = fileObj.readlines() # read all lines in file and returns them into a list
    fileObj.close
    nHeaderLines = 2 # number of lines to skip
    for line in range(nHeaderLines, len(lineList)): # loop over lines in the list   
        itemList = lineList[line].split() # split current line
        TMIN = float(itemList[12])
        TMAX = float(itemList[11])
        TAVE = float(itemList[10])
        dateList = int(itemList[9])        
        #Convert from file the date string to date time object
        formatedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dateList),"%Y%m%d").date()
        #Check the year condition and only select only that data for plotting
        if formatedDate.year in filterYear:        
            Tmin.append(TMIN)
            Tmax.append(TMAX)
            Tave.append(TAVE)
            dates.append(formatedDate)
    return Tmin,Tmax,Tave,dates
##################################################################

def MonthMean(Tave,dates):
    # Compute a new column containing the average for the month.

    # Calculate monthly mean by sum(Tave) in corresponding month and dividing by total days for that month
    sumx = 0
    cntx = 0
    thismo = -1
    column = []
    for tave, date in zip(Tave, dates):
        if date.month != thismo:
            if thismo > 0:
                column.extend( [sumx/cntx] * cntx )
            sumx = 0
            cntx = 0
            thismo = date.month
        sumx += tave
        cntx += 1

    column.extend( [sumx/cntx] * cntx )
    return column
               
def main():
    fname = 'DallasTX.txt' # initialize filename
    print('Reading file: ',fname)    
    Tmin = [] # initialize Temp list - Tmin
    Tmax = [] # initialize Temp list - Tmax
    Tave = [] # initialize Temp list - Tave
    dates = [] # initialize date list
    #Remember range is exclusive for the upper limit, So range(2010,2021,1) returns 2010 until 2020
    filterYear = range(2010,2019,1)
    #Call the ReadData() function which returns a list of min, max, Avg, Temp, date, year, month, day values
    Tmin, Tmax, Tave, dates = ReadData(fname,Tmax,Tmin,Tave,dates, filterYear) 
    dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(d),"%Y-%m-%d").date() for d in dates]  
    
    STDmin = np.std(Tmin)
    STDmax = np.std(Tmax)
    STDave = np.std(Tave)
    xT = np.arange(STDmin,STDave,STDmax)
    yT = np.exp(-xT)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex = True)
    ax = plt.gca() 
    ax.errorbar(xT,yT,xerr=0.2,yerr=0.5,fmt='o',color='yellow')
    #Set Limit for Min and Max values temp
    plt.ylim(0,120)
    plot1 = ax.plot(dates, Tmax,'red',label='Max Temp')
    plot2 = ax.plot(dates, Tmin,'blue',label='Min Temp')    
    plot3 = ax.plot(dates, Tave,'black',label='Ave Temp')
    plot4 = ax.plot(dates, MonthMean(Tave,dates), 'green', label='Monthly Mean Temp')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 90) 
    #Combine plots to get thelegends
    plots = plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + plot4
    legends = []
    for plot in plots:
        legends.append(plot.get_label())
    #Include the legends in the plots
    ax.legend(plots, legends)    
    # format your data to desired format.
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
    ax.set_xlabel('Yearly trend')
    ax.set_ylabel('Temp in Farheinhite')
    ax.set_title('Annual Temperatures at Dallas Love Field (2010-2019)')
       
main()
```

This is a small sample of data from file 'DallasTX.txt' if it's helpful:

```
          STATION_NAME                                       ELEVATION  LATITUDE   LONGITUDE  DATE     TAVG     TMAX     TMIN     
----------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140101 49       70       35       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140102 38       43       26       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140103 38       53       28       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140104 51       70       41       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140105 42       60       22       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140106 24       34       15       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140107 33       48       22       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140108 41       48       39       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140109 46       49       41       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140110 57       69       47       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140111 54       69       38       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140112 56       74       41       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140113 60       64       45       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140114 51       66       41       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140115 45       56       34       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140116 50       65       40       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140117 50       55       38       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140118 49       68       39       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140119 49       64       33       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140120 55       73       41       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140121 48       54       36       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140122 43       60       31       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140123 39       45       24       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140124 27       41       17       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140125 43       67       29       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140126 56       74       46       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140127 44       51       25       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140128 28       36       23       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140129 31       47       19       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140130 41       58       31       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20140131 60       75       50
```

Comment: You don't seem to call ``errorbar``. Why would you expect it to show any output?

Comment: Well when I do call errorbar(), I get ValueError: xerr must be a scalar or a 1D or (2, n) array-like as an output and still no error plot.

Comment: Well then why not ask about that?

Comment: I don't know, I have trouble organizing my thoughts and issues